# What is the common used library I should parse to following XML output?

Tags: java, xml, yql

Given output from [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22%29%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="4" yahoo:created="2011-01-20T06:06:19Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <quote symbol="YHOO">
            <Ask>16.47</Ask>
            <AverageDailyVolume>17453900</AverageDailyVolume>
            <Bid/>
            <AskRealtime>16.47</AskRealtime>
            <BidRealtime>0.00</BidRealtime>
            <BookValue>9.277</BookValue>
            <Change_PercentChange>-0.189 - -1.15%</Change_PercentChange>
            <Change>-0.189</Change>
            <Commission/>
            <ChangeRealtime>-0.189</ChangeRealtime>
            <AfterHoursChangeRealtime>N/A - N/A</AfterHoursChangeRealtime>
            ...
```

I was wondering what is the common used library in Java I should use to parse the output, so that I can obtain quote for a selected stock?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Common used library to parse XML respond from YQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723894/common-used-library-to-parse-xml-respond-from-yql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many.  Java has a [DOM API](http://java.sun.com/developer/codesamples/xml.html), and some other common libraries for parsing or binding are:

- [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/)
- [DOM4J](http://www.dom4j.org/)
- [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/)
- [Castor](http://www.castor.org)
- [JIBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/)
- [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

I'm pretty sure YQL also returns JSON.  In which case, I would get JSON results and use something like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse them, which might be a little bit more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the XML support that's built in: org.w3c.dom and java.xml, javax.xml.parsers et. al.